# Manifest folder is mising from previous projects

Tags: android

Whenever I make a new project in Android Studio, the manifests folder from the previous project somehow vanished
Sometimes, the manifest folder is displaced from its original location. it somehow comes out from its file location
I tried to know the reason, but all in vain